# nest js unable to create new application mac os

Tags: nestjs

I'm trying to create new nestjs project using command **nest new myApp** 
it's gives me

```
    /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/node_modules/chalk/source/index.js:103
    ...styles,
    ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/commands/command.loader.js:3:15)
```

I'm using mac os

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to update my nodejs as prerequisite from the documentation

> Prerequisites# Please make sure that Node.js (>= 10.13.0) is installed on your operating system.